# Multiple-deletions flag: Ignore zero-score answers

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, self-delete

When a user performs multiple self-deletes on answers he has provided, the [Community User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) flags them in the 10K/mod queue.

However, sometimes these users are simply getting rid of low-quality posts.
I think that it would be a good idea to limit these automatic flags to cases where the self deletion occurs on a post with a score of `>=1`.

Comment: Hm, probably you should just decline Community's bad flags with a custom decline message, explaining the situation. I've heard she's a fast learner.

Comment: I'd decline it with a nice ascii trollface, but a single-line edit box is not really good for this :p

Comment: How often do these "self deletion" flags get raised?

Comment: @Lix: Not too often, but it happens regularly.

Comment: @YannisRizos I have never known Community is a she. Now, somebody could say "picture, or it has never happened." `;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Disclaimer**
>   I am not a mod, nor a 10Ker.  My opinions here are solely based upon my experience on the site and my interactions with more veteran users and moderators.

I **disagree** with you for these reasons -

A theory once mentioned to me about flagging by a certain moderator states that it's better to raise an ultimately un-needed flag than it is to not raise a flag at all.  It's better to mark a flag as "unhelpful" than it is to miss a post **really** in need of a flag...

I agree with you that self deletion is very possibly a *responsible action* by a *responsible user* trying to keep the site clean but without manually verifying the deletion it would be impossible to differentiate a clean-up effort from rage quitting (where a user goes through all his content and deletes his/her posts)...

IMO, it would be "safer" to leave this functionality intact and leave the "decision making" to the human exception handlers.

Answer (score 1):

> However, sometimes users simply get rid of low-quality posts so I think it would be a good idea to only raise this flag if answers with a score >=1 were deleted.

I don't think "Nobody upvoted this." is a reliable indicator for low quality. Nobody upvoted it *yet*.

I have a couple of answers with a score of `0` that I know to be correct and potentially helpful. The first upvote might come after quite some time, and the answer help somebody eventually.

However, I think little of what I said above applies to answers that have been downvoted. Raising the flag only if answers with a non-negative score or **old** answers with a positive score have been deleted sounds better to me.

Comment: Similarly, **one** downvote or **one** upvote is also not the best indication...

Comment: A single vote isn't a reliable indicator for anything, but I think good answers with a score of `-1` are far less common. And you can't really blame somebody for getting rid of all the answers that cost him reputation...

Comment: Good answers with a score of `-1` are about as common as strategic dowvoters... I guess it all depends on the situation...